# sIFR not working with disabled Cookies

Tags: sifr

sIFR is working fine across browsers UNLESS cookies are disabled. When cookies are disabed, the site appears to begin to load on refresh, but then quickly turns blank to a white screen without any content and no markup in the page source. I've tried using prefetch to resolve with no success. Has anyone else experienced a similar problem?

Comment: Could you post a link? Which sIFR version is this?

Answer (score 0):

I received an email the other day asking a rather similar question, in which `sIFR.activate()` was invoked from inside `$(document).ready()`, which would break if cookies were disabled. For various reasons `sIFR.activate()` must be called directly.

I'm not sure if this is applicable to the situation as described in the question, but the coincidence is interesting.